# How to obtain url path that follows domain

Tags: python, string, url

If I have a url of http://www.example.com/myarea, what python code can I use to obtain the string "myarea"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the full path after the domain, you can use the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) module:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

x = 'http://www.example.com/myarea'
res = urlparse(x).path  # '/myarea'
```

Or you can use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to extract only the last component:

```
res = x.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1]  # 'myarea'
```

Comment: Thanks for this information! I'll likely use the first option and then trim the slashes from the front and back as needed. I'll have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @JasonHoward, Is there a particular reason this answer is unaccepted? Happy to clarify further if there is anything unclear.

Comment: Sorry. I had to play around with the solution a bit more. Initially, I thought it didn't work, but I got it:      url = request.build_absolute_uri()
    urlpath = urlparse(url).path 
    lasturlpath = urlpath.split('/')[-2]

Answer (score 1):

Split on `/` and take the last element.

```
url = "http://www.example.com/myarea"
lastElement = url.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Weird, when I print lastElement I get the output to be `myarea`